# Kernel panic during Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, windows-10, 16.10

I am aware that there is a number of similar topics, but I can not find an answer to my problem.
I had removed `Ubuntu 16.10` from my machine - removed `Linux` partitions in `Windows` (dual boot), run below command in `Ubuntu`:

```
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda
```

Now I would like to install `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`. I have followed [this](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) tutorial to create bootable `Ubuntu` USB stick. When I choose `Try Ubuntu without installing` or `Install Ubuntu` I receive a trace which part I am posting below:

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version 0x25 (or later)
Initramfs unpacking failed: LZMA data is corrupt
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu
```

My machine meets the system requirements. I have burned (followed tutorial mentioned above) USB stick twice, it did not help. I have checked file Md5sum - it is correct. Could you help me with that problem?

**EDIT:**

According to suggestions made by users `karel` and `K7AAY` I have updated BIOS on my machine and have not run below command in `Ubuntu` (I don't have access to `Ubuntu` as I had mentioned above):

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

The only result of updating BIOS is that below line is not appearing anymore, but the main problem - unability to install `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS` still exists.

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version 0x25 (or later)
```

**SECOND EDIT:**

I have prepared `Windows 10` (since on my machine `Windows 10` is installed) USB stick. I have booted on that media and selected "Repair your computer" -> "Troubleshoot" -> "Command Prompt". I have run below command and restarted the computer.

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Then I have tried one more time to install `Ubuntu` via `Ubuntu` USB stick. It has not helped, the problem still appears.

Comment: Please check the manufacturer's support website for BIOS updates, and apply them.

Comment: @karel and K7AAY: Thank you for your suggestions. Please take a look at the question after edition.

Answer (score 0):

I have burned `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS` using same burn options, but another USB stick and it solved the problem. It could be assumed that the problem lied in burning process (imho less probable) or USB stick (imho more probable). It is obvious, but if I were to give some advice to someone having this problem in the future, I would advice to just plug USB stick to another machine, choose `Try Ubuntu without installing` and observe if output would be the same. That helped me localize problem's source.